# Failed to access mail object MAPI from calling function

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm going to access Outlook MAPI folder and get mail address.Here is my method

```
 public static string GetSenderEmailAddress(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mapiObject)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PropertyAccessor oPA;
        string propName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001F";
        oPA = mapiObject.PropertyAccessor;
        string email = oPA.GetProperty(propName).ToString();
        return email;
    }
```

When button click event called,i need to fire that method and retrieve mail address.

Button click event is here.

```
      private void button3_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {

 string mailadd =  ThisAddIn.GetSenderEmailAddress(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(mailadd);

}
```

Error goes here

> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem is a 'type'which is not valid in the given context

This is my first addin,Does anyone know how to achieve this result?

Comment: Are you sure the MailItem object is valid? Where does it come from?

Comment: when i call the function in button click event error happend.It comes from the caller function

Comment: Ok, and the caller function gets it from where?

Comment: Oh, wait a sec, you are not passing the actual MailItem object, you are passing a refence to a type. The MailItem object has to come from somewhere. What is the context? Where does it need to come from? E.g. if you need the currently selected messages, use Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection collection. The currently displayed message can be retrieved from Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`RibbonControlEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribboncontroleventargs.aspx) to access the [`Context`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribboncontrol.context.aspx) which will provide you the [`MailItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861252.aspx) instance.

```
private Outlook.MailItem GetMailItem(RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    // Inspector Window
    if (e.Control.Context is Outlook.Inspector)
    {
        Outlook.Inspector inspector = e.Control.Context as Outlook.Inspector;
        if (inspector == null) return null;
        if (inspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.MailItem)
            return inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
    }
    // Explorer Window 
    if (e.Control.Context is Outlook.Explorer)
    {
        Outlook.Explorer explorer = e.Control.Context as Outlook.Explorer;
        if (explorer == null) return null; 
        Outlook.Selection selectedItems = explorer.Selection;
        if (selectedItems.Count != 1)  return null;  
        if (selectedItems[1] is Outlook.MailItem)
            return selectedItems[1] as Outlook.MailItem;
    }     
    return null;
}
```

You can add this method and then make use of it like so...

```
string mailAddress = string.Empty;
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = GetMailItem(e);
if (mailItem != null)
    mailAddress =  ThisAddIn.GetSenderEmailAddress(mailItem);
```

Comment: That is assuming a button on an Outlook ribbon. It looks like the OP has a Win Forms application.